# Download to file external hard drive

Tags: downloads

My netbook does not have enough hard drive space. I have tried to download Ubuntu to my `C:\` drive but ran out of memory. How can I download Ubuntu to an external hard drive bypassing the internal hard drive?

Comment: Are you downloading the Ubuntu .iso from the internet or are you trying to install Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Plug in your external hard drive. From the Ubuntu downloads page, right click the link to the .iso file and click 'Save Link As' and save to the external hard drive.

If you are planning on installing Ubuntu on this computer (which I assume is running Windows, since you mention a `C:\` drive) you obviously won't be able to run both Windows and Ubuntu if you are out of hard drive space. You'll have to decide if you want to keep running windows, or if you want to replace it completely with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

@amc, using "save link as" doesn't usually work.

Jim, you will need to open your browser preferences and then tell it to ask you where to save downloaded files.
Not sure if this bypasses your primary HDD completely though. It might download to the primary first and then move the files to the external source once the download is complete.

Alternatively you could lump a bunch of files, preferably audio/video from your primary to your external and then download. The ubuntu installer isn't really that big so it shouldn't take long at all.

Other options, disk defrag and/or clear cache (CCleaner is a good free program for performing maintenance like this), make sure your recycling bin is empty, delete old useless backups of your computer, remove windows indexing.